# Chance of winning PHP percent calculation

Tags: php, random, probability

I have a "battle" system, the attacker has a battle strength of e.g. 100, the defender has a strength of e.g. 75.

But I'm stuck now, I can't figure out how to find the winner.
I know the attacker has a 25% chance of loosing, but I can't figure the script.

Any ideas?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php might help you here.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: if both attacker and defender have a strenth of 100, what happens? (or is this prohibited in some way?)

Answer (score 23):

Extract a random number between `0...100`, or if you prefer `0...1`.
Than check if this number is lower than 75. If it is then the attacker won.

```
$p = rand(0,99);
if ($p<75)
  // Attacker Won!
```

This has a very straitforward probabilistic interpretation. if you extract randomly a number between `0...100` you have a 75% of chance that the number will be lower than 75. Exactly what you need.

In this case you just need `rand()` function. 
Also notice that what @Marek suggested, the winning chance for the attacker may be much lower than 75%. (read Marek answer that points to a 57% chance of winning).

The problem will arise when you need to model more complex probability density function, example:

[image]

In this case you will need a more complex model such as a [gaussian mixture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_model#Multivariate_Gaussian_mixture_model).

Comment: Of course, I was thinking way to complicated, but it's so simple. Great work, thank you!

Comment: You should check @Marek's answer. Here a weaker defender has a 75% chance of winning. That's definitely wrong.

Comment: sure I have inverted attacker/defender, fixed it

Comment: Even if you switch them, the numbers (25% versus 75%) are wrong.

Comment: @jeroen: that seems more a comment to the OP (to the question) not to this answer. If you need to model 25% vs 75%  chance of winning (what the question is asking) then my method is correct

Comment: True, but if your answer applies to the obviously wrongly drawn conclusion in the question, it's not very useful and pointing out the OP's mistake would be.

Comment: I have edited to warn the OP that he may be using the wrong relative percentage, still the method to declare a winner holds

Comment: This works, if the attacker has the most points $winChance = round((($attPoint-$defPoint)/$attPoint)*100, 2); But not when the opponent has the most.

Comment: @Sims No, it doesn't work. The number you get (25) is incorrect.

Answer (score 6):

Using a random number generator, you can create a function such as:

```
function chance($percent) {
  return mt_rand(0, 99) < $percent;
}
```

Then you can use the function anywhere. Note: `mt_rand` supposedly generates better random numbers.

Answer (score 4):

The chance of winning of player A against B is A/(A+B), this is for any number and any scale. Then use dynamic's answer to compute the actual result.

For your example:

```
$c = (75/(100+75)); // 0.42857142857142857143
$Awon = mt_rand(0, 9999) < ($c * 10000);
```

Comment: This seems to be the only correct answer as far at the math is concerned.

Comment: That's not right, player A has a 75% chance of winning and 100/(100 + 75) = 0.57, or 57%.

Comment: @Styphon That's 75 points, not percents. The total points in game is 175, player A has 75 of the total.

Comment: @Marek, no A has 100 points of the total according to the OP, B has 75 of the total.

Comment: @Styphon You cannot translate relative strenghts to winning percentages like that. The chance of the stronger winning here is really 57% and not 75%.

Comment: @Styphon You are right on that, but those are just names, math is the same.

Comment: @Styphon You've said it yourself: `75 of the total`. What do you think the total is?

Comment: @jeroen, the total is 175.

Comment: @jeroen You're assuming that the op is basing percentage of winning as a total of two users available points. Whilst I agree, that's probably what the OP originally intended and wants, it's now what he asked for. All we know from the OPs original statement is that A has a 25% chance of losing.

Comment: @Styphon The OP will probably have gotten the message by now :-)

Answer (score 3):

If I were to pop this into code as a usable function:

```
function attack($attack, $defend)
{
    return (mt_rand(1, $attack) > $defend);
}

$attack = 100;
$defend = 75;

var_dump(attack(100,75));
```

Will simply return true or false as required. Pass in whichever values that you need.